# Pretrained CNN(tensorflow/darknet/caffe) weights for human/vehicle detection only

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe, yolo

I am making use of tensorflow's pretrained weights from [Tensorflow detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#coco-trained-models-coco-models) , which is primarily trained on [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/) datasets , which covers about 80 different classes including humans, so making use of these models certainly results in higher computational trade-off, so is there any publicly open pre-trained weights which only focuses on one class in this case either human or vehicle(car).

If there is no such models available then how it is possible to fine-tune or customize these existing models like,

"**ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28**" , which performs pretty well with *mAP of  32 and computationally efficient as well* , so how such models can be utilized to detect only humans but not any other objects.

Comment: Follow the instructions from the GitHub repo you linked and fine-tune any model you want on [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/) data set. KITTI contains both car and pedestrian class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the model [person-vehicle-bike-detection-crossroad-1016](https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/blob/develop/models/intel/person-vehicle-bike-detection-crossroad-1016/description/person-vehicle-bike-detection-crossroad-1016.md) ?